# How do i solve css problem while developing theme on wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am developing my theme using undersocres.me for wordpress. When i started to
develop and used

```
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
```

> it showed error .

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
```

> bootstrap.css:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `wp_enqueue_style` instead of `wp_enqueue_script`

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
```

Comment: yes it worked very much . i did so careless. thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

Just change get template directory to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and the enqueue to `wp_enqueue_style`

Example:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/